# Spring oauth2 retains user credentials after authorization_Code

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

In our application we have below flow:

1. First request is of grant_type authorization_code.
2. On success of above request user is redirected to login page to  enter credentials.
3. New token is generated and User is logged in.

Now, if we keep the server up and repeat the above steps,then user is not redirected to login page. Instead credentials entered in above iteration are taken and new token is generated. It seems user data is being retained by spring.

Can someone pls help to identify the root cause? Do we have to invalidate the session manually? how?

Regards,
Smita

Answer (score 0):

That is default behavior it will keep the user authenticated.

But if you want to change that. You add this in your Authorization Server Config

```
@Autowired
public void configureAuthorizationEndpoint(AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint) {
    DefaultRedirectResolver redirectResolver = new DefaultRedirectResolver() {
        @Override
        public String resolveRedirect(String requestedRedirect, ClientDetails client) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            return super.resolveRedirect(requestedRedirect, client);
        }
    };
    redirectResolver.setMatchPorts(false);
    authorizationEndpoint.setRedirectResolver(redirectResolver);
}
```

It will basically reset the authentication right before it sends the authorization_code to the relying party. So if you add this, the user will always be redirect to login page for each request.